# How do I access a file outside of my xap file in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm having some troubles accessing a video file that sits right outside of my xap file. Is it possible to access this file using `Application.GetResourceStream()`?

If I put `test.wmv` in the root of my xap file then the following works as expected:

```
                        Uri uri = new Uri("test.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
                        h.Resource.Stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;
```

However, If I put `test.wmv` outside of my xap file, but in the same directory then I'd expect the following to work:

```
                    Uri uri = new Uri("/../test.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
                    h.Resource.Stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;
```

But it doesn't and I end up catching the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I presume that means that it can't access or find `test.wmv`

Can anyone help me with this?

Maybe it isn't possible to use `GetResourceStream()` for this because it expects a relative URI with respect to the xap file. In that case, what other method can I use?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190632%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

[Silverlight Forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/123145/304461.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking to create a Uri to a resource relative to your xap file?  This should accomplish that.

```
new Uri(App.Current.Host.Source, "../test.wmv");
```

Comment: This looks promising but it says: Expected relative URI, found absolute.

Comment: Did you get rid of the UriKind.Relative when you ran this code?

Comment: Yes, I did get rid of that. Do I need it?

Comment: No - it should be exactly as I pasted it - did you by chance keep your starting slash?  If so, kill it.  It should be ../test.wmv  NOT  /../test.wmv